# Typescript: typing only the arguments or the return type of a function

Tags: typescript

I'm having several functions that accept different arguments but all of them return a function with the same signature:

```
const createSum5 = () => (c: number) => c + 5;
const createMultiplyN = (n: number) => (c: number) => n * c;
const createWordsSum = (word: string) => (c: number) => word.length + c;
```

The return type is always `(c: number) => number`. Is there a way that I can type this return value for all the functions, without typing the argument? So that I could short them to this without losing type safety:

`createSum5: /* Something here */ = () => c => c + 5;`

---

I've tried these, but:

1.This solution loses type-safety: `type NumericArg = (...args: any) => (c: number) => number`;

2.I could write the function signature for every function in advance:

```
type Nfunction = (c: number) => number;
type createSum5Type = () => Nfunction;
...
const createSum5: createSum5Type = () => c => c + 5;
```

But that would be tedious. I want Typescript to automatically infer the arguments as it would do if I don't specify the types.

Is there any other way? Can the opposite be done (specifying functions with the same signature but let Typescript infer the return type?).

---

EDIT #1:
Here's an example when I speak about the opposite:

```
const func1: /* Something here */ = num => '#'.repeat(5);
const func2: /* Something here */ = num => num * num;
```

Both func1 and func2 have the same signature `(num: number)` but different return types. I want Typescript to infer that every time I call func1 the return type is a `string`, but with `func2` the return type is a number.

---

EDIT #2:

My use case is not relevant, but I'll add it anyway. I'm developing a React-redux application using Thunks. Every thunk always returns a function with signature `(dispatch, getState) => void` but they may accept different parameters. After some research this is the less verbose version that I could find:

`const onFetchUser = (userIds: number[]) : ThunkFunction = dispatch => { ... }`.

If there was a way to allow Typescript to infer the arguments but let me set the return type (which is my question here), I could make it easier to read like this:

`const onFetchUser: /* something here */ = (userIds: number[]) => dispatch => {...}`.

Comment: What's the use case?   What breaks for you if you don't just let the compiler infer the types as in your first example?  Are you trying to prevent something like `const oops = (word: string) => (c: number) => word + c` from compiling?

Comment: I have a React Redux application using Thunks for async actions. After some research I manage to simplify the signature to `const onFetchUsers = (userIds: number[]) : ThunkFunction = (dispatch, getState) => { ... }`. As you can guess if I were to type both the Dispatch and the getState parameters, it would be too verbose. Right now I still have to type the return type (in this case `ThunkFunction`) for every async function. I'm curious if I can reduce the verbosity even further.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is the only option, but one option is to use a helper function that has a generic parameter that will capture the actual type of the function passed in but that will also enforce a return type of `(c: number)=> number`.

```
function fn<T extends (...a: any[]) => (c: number) => number>(o: T) {
  return o;
}
const createSum5 = fn(() => c => c + 5)
const createMultiplyN = fn((n: number) => c => n * c);
const createWordsSum = fn((word: string) => c => word.length + c);
```

I don't believe another option exists, typescript does not in general allow partial inference for variables (or more specifically constrained inference) this can only be done with a function.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript supports the keyword `infer`, which would allow you to preserve the types of arguments and/or return types of a function.

For conditional types, it would look like this:

```
type ReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : any;
```

There is some info about infer here:
 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

**Update:**

You can do it just by using a generic function:

```
type numFunc<T> = (arg: T) => (c: number) => number; 

const createSum5: numFunc<void> = () => (c: number) => c + 5;
const createMultiplyN: numFunc<number> = (n: number) => (c: number) => n * c;
const createWordsSum: numFunc<string> = (word: string) => (c: number) => word.length + c;

const createSumString: numFunc<number> = () => (c: number) => 'Hello';  //error
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of how to use the `infer`keyword? I may be using it wrong. Not sure how to make it work for the cases that I put in the question.

Comment: Note that a similar `ReturnType` type function is [part of the standard TS library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1471-L1474).  This answer seems to be in response to the part of the question that says "Can the opposite be done (specifying functions with the same signature but let Typescript infer the return type?)"

Comment: @jcalz can you post an example of that in a separated answer? I'll update the question with examples.

Comment: @clovis1122 Updated the answer - no need to use conditional types.

Comment: Thanks @YakovFain! This is very close to what I need. Some issues: #1 Cannot easily extend it to multiple arguments (tried using `(...args: T)` but got an error). #2 It  seems like the parameter names are lost when hovering over the function using VSCode - which gives me the idea that Typescript might not be detecting it.

Comment: To allow several arguments of the same type, you can use ```type numFunc<T> = (...arg: Array<T>) => (x: number) => number; ``` Not sure if it makes sense to make it even more generic.

Comment: Thank you @YakovFain, for my specific use case it does make sense to have multiple parameters from different types. It would even be OK if the `numFunc` didn't specify the parameters - just the return type.